# multiple mysql query result in single array

Tags: php, html, mysql

how can i add result of multiple queries in a single array so it makes it easier to later output.

for example,

```
$newArray = array("mike", "john");
while ($newArray !== false){
    $sql = "Select * from accounts where name = '$newArray'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_connection,$sql);
}

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf $row['firstName'];
    echo "----";
    printf $row['num_accounts'];
    echo "----";
    prinf $row['location'];
    echo "----";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

i am sure i am missing something that obvious.  but the idea is that i want to setup a loop to read from an array and then execute the query and store the results.  each time query executes the condition is different but from same table, , but then keep adding the results to single output, making it easier to output in the end.

Comment: I would recommend reading some basic tutorial about MySQL queries to get better acquainted with the technology's capabilities. There are so many things you can do.

Answer (score 1):

you could avoid the while simple using in clause  based on list of values you need

```
$newList = "'mike', 'john'";

$sql = "Select * from accounts where name IN (" .$newList .")";
```

but you should not use php var in sql ..you are at risk for sqlinjection .. for avoid this  you should take a look at your sqldruver for binding param  ..

but if you want append the result for different where condition on same table you should take a look at UNION clause

```
$sql = "Select * from accounts where name IN (" .$newList .") 
        UNION 
        Select * from accounts  where you_col > 10";
```

Comment: thanks for prompt response.  just out of curiosity, how will this loop through the array to query for different conditions?

Comment: If you use the in clause you don't need  loop for select  result  related  to the values in the list .. but if you want select the same table with different where clause  you should take a look at UNION clause for append several query (with correspondig column data type and number.. answer updated .. with a brief sample

Comment: Quite like this solution. It will always be faster executing via SQL rather than php. You can `implode(','$newArray)` to easily get the data that this query requires.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with your code..
1. You are inputting a full array into your query.
2. You're doing no preparations on your query thus it's vulnerable to sql   injection if `$newArray` is human input data.
3. Your logic from looping thru the data, if you managed to get a single query correct, would always loop thru the last query. You need to move the `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` stuff inside your actual loop.

To get this code working it would look like so:

```
$newArray = array("mike", "john");
foreach($newArray as $name){
    $sql = "Select * from accounts where name = '{$name}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_connection,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf $row['firstName'];
        echo "----";
        printf $row['num_accounts'];
        echo "----";
        prinf $row['location'];
        echo "----";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```